# Atom - incorrect theming in i3 on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gtk, atom-editor, i3-window-manager

I'm using the Ambiance Blackout GTK2/3 theme on i3 in Arch Linux.

Most applications are themed correctly, but Atom in particular is using the wrong colors on dropdown menus, which I can't find a fix for.

[image: Screenshot]

[My configuration files (GitHub)](https://github.com/BenClegg/dotfiles)